# add different classes to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects, where each object has a textValue, an active, info, etc. This arrangement I walk through and show buttons for each element. To each button inside I add a div and inside 3 paragraphs, I'm trying to add classes and display some of the paragraphs by condition to each button. I add an event to the button and pass it an id, with this I set the active to true and show information, this for each different id. Clicking on a button makes an active class and shows a quantity, clicking outside or on the button itself eliminates the class and the quantity (p), when I click on a button information opens, here I have a button that when clicking, the div with the information is hidden (I already do this) and I want to keep the class visible and the paragraph visible, I'm using conditionals for this, but I can't do it, this is the code:

```
<button 
  v-for="filter in addedFilters" 
  :key="filter" 
  :value="filter.textValue" 
  @click="(e) => {openInfoFiltro(filter, e)}" 
  :class="{'filter-active': filter.active && !optionButtonValue.includes(filter.textValue),  'active-filter-options': filter.active && optionButtonValue.includes(filter.textValue)}">
      <div>
         <p v-if="filter.active && filter.textValue !== 'Uso de suelo' && filter.textValue !== 'Amenidades' && filter.textValue !== 'Clasificación de la tierra' & filter.textValue !== 'Vocaciones'" class="m-0">
           {{ $filters.numeralFormatBtnInfo(filter.info[0]) }} - {{$filters.numeralFormatBtnInfo(filter.info[1]) }}
         </p>

         <p v-else-if="filter.active || filter.textValue === 'Uso de suelo' && filter.textValue === 'Amenidades' && filter.textValue === 'Clasificación de la tierra' && filter.textValue === 'Vocaciones'" class="m-0 amount"> 
             <span v-if="filter.info">({{filter.info === 0 ? '' : filter.info }})</span>
         </p>

         <p class="m-0">{{filter.textValue}}</p>
      </div>
  </button>
```

function when clicking on the button and setting the active of the object to true

```
const openInfoFiltro = (id,e) => {
    selectedFilter.value = addedFilters.value.find(val => val.textValue === id.textValue);
    console.log(selectedFilter.value)
    if(selectedFilter.value){
        selectedFilter.value.active = !selectedFilter.value.active
    }    
}
```

array where i have the different text Value

```
const optionButtonValue = ['Uso de suelo', 'Amenidades', 'Clasificación de la tierra', 'Vocaciones' ]
```

In another component I go through provide and reject the ref, where I pass the selected filter (selectedFilter) and here I have a function where when clicked, I want the button to remain active and depending on the optionButtonValue, show one paragraph or the other, but leave it active, right here I pass the active to false to hide the information of each button

```
const showResults = () => {
  console.log('Mostrar resultados')
  landsStore.lands = []
  landsStore.landsadd = []
  selectedFilter.value.active = false

  landsStore.fetchLands('', { filters: filtersStore.getAllFiltersAlgoliaFormat, facetFilters: filtersStore.getAllFacetFilterFormat })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, v-if waits from you only true and false. But you are use in v-if text definition. This is not correctly. Firstly, you can change v-if only conditionally like v-if="{filter.active || filter} " also in your p tag you can type define directly change text {{ filter.active && 'bla bla' }}